# Can't understand the meaning of a sentence: 「使い物にならなきゃ 素手でやるだけか」

Tags: grammar, manga

So, I've been reading a manga and there is a phrase that I can't get. It says:

> 使い物にならなきゃ
>   素手でやるだけか

Those two sentences are separated.
So what I understand about is that if the thing is useless he has to use his bare hands. To give more context they are talking about using a knife.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's parse your sentences to try to make it a bit clearer:

> **使い物**  = a usable item
>   **に**   = (change of state)
>   **ならなきゃ** = ならなければ = if it doesn't become / if it isn't
>   **素手で**  = with bare hands
>   **やる**  = do
>   **だけ**  = only / no other option
>   **か** = question / rhetorical device

You mentioned that the context was that this is about a knife. So we can separate this into two clauses:

**使い物にならなきゃ** If it's not usable  (*If I can't use this knife*),
**素手でやるだけか**  I guess there's no choice but to use my bare hands.

Without the full context, it's a little difficult to decide on the best translation since I don't know what the character is trying to do. But hopefully parsing it in that way makes the intended meaning clearer.

Comment: Thanks, and for parse the sentence, it was really helpful